# how to retrieve text from a variable stored in a list python

Tags: python, list

So I am trying to store multiple variables in a list, each variable contains text. After that, I would like to perform some analysis on the text which is stored inside the variable that is stored in the list.

Code:

```
my_list = list[]

var_1 = 'I have lots of text'
var_2 = 'I have even more text'
var_3 = 'but wait there is more'

my_list.append('var_1','var_2','var_3')

for var in my_list:
    x = package.function('var')
    print x
```

what ends up happening is that the function is performed on the variable name not the text that is stored inside it. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This is not valid python code. Please show us the actual code you're using

Comment: Use `my_list = list()` in your first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_1 = 'I have lots of text'
var_2 = 'I have even more text'
var_3 = 'but wait there is more'

my_list = [var_1, var_2, var_3]

for var in my_list:
    x = package.function(var)
    print x
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are storing the string representation of your variable names:

```
my_list.append('var_1','var_2','var_3')
```

Furthermore, you cannot use the append like this. What you want to do is actually put in your variable names like this:

```
my_list = [var_1, var_2, var_3]
```

Finally, you are accessing your list index as 'var' in your loop:

```
for var in my_list:
    x = package.function('var')
    print(x)
```

to this:

```
for var in my_list:
    x = package.function(var)
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

As a new Python learning, i found some issue in your code.

Issue 1. This is how you declare a list in python.

```
my_list=list()
```

Issue 2. list.append method takes only 1 argument. So you can not pass all 3 variables at a same time.

```
 my_list = list()
 var_1 = 'I have lots of text'
 var_2 = 'I have even more text'
 var_3 = 'but wait there is more'

 #append all variables in list:
 my_list.append(var_1)
 my_list.append(var_2)
 my_list.append(var_3)

 #first way to print:
 for var in my_list:
    print var

 #second way to print:
 print my_list

 #third way to print:
 for idx,item in enumerate(my_list):
     print idx ,":", item
```